# Kivy: change layout when I change orientation

Tags: python, widget, kivy

I want to create something that changes its general layout when the orientation, or size, of the window is changed.  In the below example, I was trying to do this with 3 buttons.  But it fails, and complains that the buttons already have a parent when I try to add them to a layout.  Why do they already have a parent?  I never added them to the AdaptWidget...
More importantly, how *should* I achieve what I want to achieve?
Code below:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class AdaptWidget(BoxLayoutWrite failed: Broken pipe
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(AdaptWidget, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.but1 = Button(text='but1')
        self.but2 = Button(text='but2')
        self.but3 = Button(text='but3')
        self.layout = None

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.clear_widgets()

        if self.size[0] > self.size[1]:
            self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
            self.but1.size_hint = 0.7, 1

            self.layout.add_widget(self.but1)
            vert = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
            self.layout.add_widget(vert)
            self.but2.size_hint = (1,0.5)
            self.but3.size_hint = (1,0.5)
            vert.add_widget(self.but2)
            vert.add_widget(self.but3)
        else:
            self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
            self.but1.size_hint = 1, 0.7
            self.layout.add_widget(self.but1)
            horiz = BoxLayout(oreintation='horizontal')
            self.layout.add_widget(horiz)
            self.but2.size_hint = 0.5, 1
            self.but3.size_hint = 0.5, 1
            horiz.add_widget(self.but2)
            horiz.add_widget(self.but3)

        self.add_widget(self.layout)

class TestLayoutApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AdaptWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestLayoutApp().run()
```

Comment: can you not use **ScreenManager** and just **switch_to** another layout when **on_size()**?

Answer (score 1):

Every time the size of your `AdaptWidget` changes, your `on_size` callback runs - but the callback doesn't remove any widgets from their parents, so `on_size` will always crash the second time it is called. You can always ensure a widget is removed from its parent:

```
if widget.parent is not None:
    widget.parent.remove_widget(widget)
```

Answer (score 0):

2. EDIT:

3 days ago I wrote this "answer", although I could not make the above suggestions work.

But now someone here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/Z5fjt5tNys8
Showed me how to do it.

So here comes the solution:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class AdaptWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(AdaptWidget, self).__init__(**kw)
        # but1 = Button(id='but1', text='button1')
        # but1 = ObjectProperty(None)
        # self.but1 = ObjectProperty(None)
        self.add_widget(Button(id='but1', text='button1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(id='but2', text='button2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(id='but3', text='button3'))

    def on_size(self, *args):
        if self.width > self.height:
            self.orientation = 'horizontal'
            # self.child.but1.size_hint = (0.7, 1)
            # but1.size_hint = (0.7, 1)
            # self.ids.but1.size_hint = (0.7, 1)
            self.children[2].size_hint = (0.7, 1)
            self.children[1].size_hint = (0.5, 1)
            self.children[0].size_hint = (0.5, 1)
        else:
            self.orientation = 'vertical'
            self.children[2].size_hint = (1, 0.7)
            self.children[1].size_hint = (1, 0.5)
            self.children[0].size_hint = (1, 0.5)


class TestLayoutApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AdaptWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestLayoutApp().run()
```

Note that the solution above is much cleaner than the original code. No need to remove or clear any widgets. You just change their attributes.

1. EDIT:

Part of the problem was that the 'buildozer.spec'-file contained this:

```
# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait
```

Instead of this:

```
# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = all
```